# how to find array in mongodb nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js

```
bookHistory:(memberId)=>{

        return new Promise(async(resolve,reject)=>{
           const historyData=await db.get().collection('bookborrow').find({userId:(memberId)}).toArray()
            const bookid=  await historyData.map(element => {
                 return element.data.bookname
             }) 
              console.log(bookid)
              const getBookName=await db.get().collection('bookdetails').find({_id:{$in:[objectid[bookid]]}}).toArray()
              console.log(getBookName)
     })
   }
```

historyData is output is look like
['62e53c1ff5d4c45fb7853d9e','62ea6268fd2fe8616cd4c17b']
and i need to data get this _id data from another collection

Comment: Can you please rephrase your problem? It is very hard to understand. Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask, https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example and https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help.

Answer (score 1):

I suppose you meant to do a search using the ids array. If so, this should work.

```js
import {Types} from 'mongoose';

const historyData=await db.get().collection('bookborrow').find({userId:(memberId)}).toArray()
const bookIds = await historyData.map(element => {
    return new Types.ObjectId(element.data.bookname)
}) 

const getBookName = await db.get().collection('bookdetails').find({
      _id: {
        $in: bookIds
      },
}).toArray()
```